# Why didn't Margaret mention Ian's attempt to kill her

Tags: plot-explanation, a-very-british-scandal

In *A Very British Scandal*, in court, very much is made of Margaret's infidelity as being the cause of the divorce, and she accuses Ian (though without evidence) of having an affair of his own.

However, she never mentions that at one point, after the money dried up, Ian tried to strangle her! An off hand remark is made about physical violence, which Ian simply denies, but there is a witness to this incident as a servant came into the room while it was happening.

Why did this not come up in court? Surely it would have been significant in Margaret's favour?

There were other similar incidents which were simply brushed aside (Ian's drinking, him breaking into and burglarising her house, terrorising her in her bed, etc.) Why didn't Margaret make more of all this?